# Dynamically set the cell contents of a DataGridColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I'm creating a dynamic UI application in WPF MVVM that binds areas of the UI to a collection of my custom `UIField` class.

`UIField` contains a number of `BindingProperty` properties that allow me the specify the property the `Control` will bind to.

```
public abstract class UIField : BaseObject
{
    BindingProperty property, isReadonly = new BindingProperty(false, false);
    object dataContext;

    public BindingProperty Property
    {
        get { return property; }
        set { SetProperty(ref property, value, () => Property); }
    }
    public BindingProperty IsReadonly
    {
        get { return isReadonly; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isReadonly, value, () => IsReadonly); }
    }
    public object DataContext
    {
        get { return dataContext; }
        set { SetProperty(ref dataContext, value, () => DataContext); }
    }
}
```

In a `ResourceDictionary` I template the derived classes of `UIField`

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type fields:TextBoxField}">
    <TextBox metro:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="{e:IndirectBinding Watermark}" 
             metro:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="{e:IndirectBinding UseFloatingWatermark}"
             IsReadOnly="{e:IndirectBinding IsReadonly}"
             Text="{e:IndirectBinding Property}"                 
              />
</DataTemplate>
```

And I then create these fields in the view model and add them to a collection. The UI then binds to the collection using an `ItemsControl`

```
new TextBoxField()
{
    DataContext = this,
    Property = new BindingProperty(() => ((SalesOrder)Order).SecondSalesReference),
    Watermark = new BindingProperty("Customer Ref. Number", false),
    UseFloatingWatermark = new BindingProperty(true, false)
 }
```

This is working great for normal fields but I'm running into a problem with `DataGrid`.

Preferably, I would like to be able to bind a collection of `UIField`s that have been extended to provide a Header property to the columns of a `DataGrid` and then template these to `DataGridColumn`s but you can't have a `DataGridColumn` in a `DataTemplate`.

Currently, I've created an interface that gives me the header, `DataGridColumn` type and the contents that should be in each cell:

```
public interface IDataGridField
{
    string Header { get; set; }

    Type ColumnType { get; }

    UIField CellContents { get; }
}
```

I then bind these to a `DataGrid`s columns using:

```
public class DataGridHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableColumnsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindableColumns", typeof(ThreadSafeCollection<IDataGridField>), typeof(DataGridHelper),new UIPropertyMetadata(null, BindableColumnsPropertyChanged));
    static void BindableColumnsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGrid = source as DataGrid;
        var columns = e.NewValue as ThreadSafeCollection<IDataGridField>;
        dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
        if (columns == null)
            return;

        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            var newColumn = Utility.CreateInstance(column.ColumnType) as DataGridColumn;
            newColumn.Header = column.Header;
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(newColumn);
        }
    }
    public static void SetBindableColumns(DependencyObject element, ThreadSafeCollection<IDataGridField> value)
    {
        element.SetValue(BindableColumnsProperty, value);
    }
    public static ThreadSafeCollection<IDataGridField> GetBindableColumns(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (ThreadSafeCollection<IDataGridField>)element.GetValue(BindableColumnsProperty);
    }
}
```

This will give me columns with headers but no content in the `DataGridCell`s.

How can I set the contents of each cell in the `DataGridColumn` created?

**EDIT 1 (Progress?):**

I realised that the `DataGridColumn` generated has to be a `DataGridTemplateColumn` so this opens up a few more properties.

I've modified `IDataGridField`, changing the `UIField` property to a `Type` instead.

Then, when generating the new `DataGridColumn` I just get the `DataTemplate` assigned to the selected `Type`

```
foreach (var column in columns)
{
    var newColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
    var key = new DataTemplateKey(column.CellContentType);
    var template = Application.Current.FindResource(key) as DataTemplate;
    newColumn.CellTemplate = template;
    newColumn.Header = column.Header;
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(newColumn);
}
```

I think the only problem now is applying the bindings.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to reinvent the wheel. The WPF DataGrid handle basic DataTypes like string, bool, int already quite well. But you will have your reasons why.

I think if you want to go for dynamic approach you want to set the `CellTemplate` or/and `CellEditingTemplate` instead of creating the "correct" column type. This would also work for more complex datatypes.

This is just XAML but it should show the direction you could go:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox metro:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="{e:IndirectBinding Watermark}" 
             metro:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="{e:IndirectBinding UseFloatingWatermark}"
             IsReadOnly="{e:IndirectBinding IsReadonly}"
             Text="{e:IndirectBinding Property}"                 
              />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You could also use the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event of the datagrid to override the creation of columns. Maybe you want to derive your CustomDataGrid?

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    //check for the type
    if (e.PropertyType == typeof(TextField))
    {
        DataGridTemplateColumn newDataGridTemplateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        e.Column = newDataGridTemplateColumn;

        //do some datatemplate voodoo, maybe you want to load it from resources or similar
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(
@"<DataTemplate 
xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""> 
    <" + typeof(ComboBox).Name + @" Text=""{Binding " + "Text" + @"}""/> 
</DataTemplate>");
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        DataTemplate template = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;

        newDataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate = template;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it would give me the same DataTemplate for the same Type. I need to be able to specify different properties (IsReadonly etc.). I think my best bet may be overriding DataGridTemplateColumn and GenerateElement()